# why is $(this) selector pointing to what it does in this function?

Tags: jquery

What I am confused about is why $(this) is pointing to '#navigation a' objects and not '#navigation_blob' object?  To be clear I know what $(this) does. I am just confused about the scoping in this example.

Thanks!

*Taken from "Jquery novice to ninja":*

```
$('#navigation a').hover(function() {
    // Mouse over function
    $('#navigation_blob').animate(
        {width: $(this).width() + 10, left: $(this).position().left},
        {duration: 'slow', easing: 'easeOutElastic', queue: false}
    );
}, function() {
    // Mouse out function
    var leftPosition = $('#navigation li:first a').position().left;
    $('#navigation_blob').animate(
        {width:'hide'},
        {duration:'slow', easing: 'easeOutCirc', queue:false}
    ).animate({left: leftPosition}, 'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` points to the context on which it was invoked. jQuery passes the element you searched as the context, hence `this` point to `'#navigation a'`.

`$(this)` takes the DOM element (referred by `this`) and wraps it in a jQuery object.

Inside `$('#navigation_blob').animate()`, `this` will point to `'navigation_blob'`.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but isn't '#navigation_blob' a context itself?  It returns an object does it not?  I mean shouldn't the inner function override what *this is referring to?

Comment: Yeah, but it won't override. Simply because it establishes a new scope (javascript variables are scoped to the function). So `this` in the inner funtion will refer to `navigation_blob` without overriding `this` in parent function. If you wish to access parent `this`, you need a closure: IN parent:  `var self = this;` IN inner function: `$(self); // will give navigation a`

Comment: `#navigation_blob` is a DOM element, jquery searches the DOM. `this` returns the DOM element which calls the function. If you want to use `#navigation a` instead of `#navigation_blob`, use sth like: `var nav_a = this;` in your `#navigation a`'s hover function

Answer (score 1):

There are a few pieces in play when determining what a variable name is bound to:

1. JS has function scope and global scope, so you'll only get a new variable when code is executed globally, or inside a function definition when you use the `var` keyword to define the variable. Otherwise, when a function is defined a variable name is bound to whatever exists in the scope the function is defined in, considering nesting function definitions in turn, right on up to global scope.
2. Unlike other variable names, `this` is special; it's never bound in a closure. This is important because otherwise the scope where a function is defined would come into play.
3. In event listeners, some browsers bind `this` to the element the listener was registered on, as if the event listener were a method of the element. IE (through version 8) didn't perform this binding; as a result, it was bound to the global object (`window`), the same as when any other free function (i.e. function not bound to an object) is called. As far as I know, no standard addresses either behavior. The relevant standard should be the DOM Event standards, such as the [ECMAScript Language Binding](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/ecma-script-binding.html) appendix for DOM Level 2.

The call to `animate` on `#navigation_blob` doesn't involve defining a new function, so the scope of `this` is the event handler. jQuery enforces the non-IE binding behavior, ensuring `this` refers to `#navigation a`.